# How can I add a new character to an existing keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I currently have the *Greek (Polytonic)* keyboard layout installed, and it works wonderfully for typing Ancient Greek.

However, I sometimes find myself needing to type the obscure letter digamma (capital Ϝ, lowercase ϝ), which isn't available on this keyboard. Ideally I'd move the final sigma to the Q key, and put digamma on the W.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I found [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions), but it warns me that it's not updated for current versions of Ubuntu. Moreover, digamma is too obscure to be given a name in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` (though it does have suitable codepoints in Unicode), and I'm not sure what I'd have to recompile if I edited that file.

Comment: If it's only one or two symbols you want to change, I'd suggest that you simply try to edit the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gr` file directly.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried that, but unfortunately this character isn't defined in keysymdef.h (so it has no name I can use, and I have no idea how to use a codepoint in place of a defined name).

Comment: XKB understands the notation `U03DC` and `U03DD`. No need to mess with `keysymdef.h`.

Comment: Oh, if that works, that's exactly what I need. Feel free to post it as an answer!

Comment: I suggest that you try it, and if it proves to work for you, please feel free to submit an answer with the solution. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Gunnar Hjalmarsson pointed out in the comments, xkb understands Unicode codepoints as well as named characters.

I replaced the final sigma key with this:

```
key <AD02> { [                 U03DD,          U03DC ] }; // ϝ Ϝ
```

And after a reboot, everything works as expected!